# how to redirect this perl script's output to file?

Tags: linux, shell, perl

I don't have much experience with perl, and would appreciate any/all feedback....

[Before I start: I do not have access/authority to change the existing perl scripts.]

I run a couple perl scripts several times a day, but I would like to begin capturing their output in a file.

The first perl script does not take any arguments, and I'm able to "tee" its output without issue:

```
/asdf/loc1/rebuild-stuff.pl 2>&1 | tee $mytmpfile1
```

The second perl script hangs with this command:

```
/asdf/loc1/create-site.pl --record=${newsite} 2>&1 | tee $mytmpfile2
```

FYI, the following command does NOT hang:

```
/asdf/loc1/create-site.pl --record=${newsite} 2>&1
```

I'm wondering if /asdf/loc1/create-site.pl is trying to process the `| tee $mytmpfile2` as additional command-line arguments? I'm not permitted to share the entire script, but here's the beginning of its main routine:

```
...
my $fullpath = $0;
$0 =~ s%.*/%%;

# Parse command-line options.
...
Getopt::Long::config ('no_ignore_case','bundling');
GetOptions ('h|help'               => \$help,
            'n|dry-run|just-print' => \$preview,
            'q|quiet|no-mail'      => \$quiet,
            'r|record=s'           => \$record,
            'V|noverify'           => \$skipverify,
            'v|version'            => \$version) or exit 1;
...
```

Does the above code provide any clues? Other than modifying the script, do you have any tips for allowing me to capture its output in a file?

Comment: No, the code you provided here does not provide any clues. Please test before asking that you're providing a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code that lets someone else see the problem firsthand when run without changes.

Comment: To be clear, your script can't possibly process the `| tee ...` itself; that operation is performed by the shell before the script is even started, so the perl script has no ability to change the `tee` invocation. It **does** have the ability to check whether its stdout and stderr are to a TTY or a FIFO and change its behavior on that basis, but none of the code you gave here does that check.

Comment: It's also notable that default buffering behavior can change based on the FIFO / TTY determination; see [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) for some introductory discussion.

Answer (score 5):

It's not hanging. You are "suffering from buffering". Like most programs, Perl's STDOUT is buffered by default. Like most programs, Perl's STDOUT is flushed by a newline when connected to a terminal, and block buffered otherwise. When STDOUT isn't connected to a terminal, you won't get any output until 4 KiB or 8 KiB of output is accumulated (depending on your version of Perl) or the program exits.

You could add `$| = 1;` to the script to disable buffering for STDOUT. If your program ends with a true value or exits using `exit`, you can do that without changing the `.pl` file. Simply use the following wrapper:

```
perl -e'
   $| = 1;
   $0 = shift;
   do($0);
   my $e = $@ || $! || "$0 didn\x27t return a true value\n";
   die($e) if $e;
' -- prog args | ...
```

Or you could fool the program into thinking it's connected to a terminal using `unbuffer`.

```
unbuffer prog args | ...
```

Comment: `unbuffer` is a far worse solution -- to the point where I'd tend to suggest not offering it with a simple Perl-native fix available. It requires Expect, and thus a TCL interpreter, to run -- so you're substantially expanding the dependency chain, impacting startup time and memory usage, &c.

Comment: Re "*`unbuffer` is a far worse solution*", Why do you say that? And worse than what? I'm not aware of any other similar tool.

Comment: That explanation is present in my comment -- try reloading? Short answer is the dependency chain; `unbuffer` is written in `expect`, so when you run a Perl script under `unbuffer`, you're launching two separate script interpreters where otherwise you'd only need one.

Comment: You already offered an alternative yourself -- `$| = 1`. I'm suggesting doubling down on it. :)

Comment: That requires changing the program, and thus not an alternative.

Comment: ...that said, in terms of "and worse than what", see the `stdbuf` utility included on GNU platforms -- though it's only applicable if Perl doesn't change stdout's buffering settings in absence of explicit directives.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, `stdbuf -o 0 perl -e'print "a"; sleep(2); print "b"'` doesn't work.

Comment: `$| = 1; require 'other-script.pl'`

Comment: @Charles Duffy, Added a wrapper example.

Comment: For a more targeted hack, you could `LD_PRELOAD` a library that overrides `isatty(1)` only.

Comment: If you don't want to change the script, you could put `$| = 1;` in `AutoFlush.pm` and run it as `perl -MAutoFlush prog.pl ...`.

Comment: @melpomene, or `PERL5OPT=-MAutoFlush prog.pl` (to avoid ignoring the shebang line)